# How does (i << 48) | ((i & 0xffff0000L) << 16) | ((i >>> 16) & 0xffff0000L) | (i >>> 48) work?

Tags: java, long-integer, bit

Here is the implementation of reverse in Long:

```
public static long reverse(long i) {
        // HD, Figure 7-1
    i = (i & 0x5555555555555555L) << 1 | (i >>> 1) & 0x5555555555555555L;//1
    i = (i & 0x3333333333333333L) << 2 | (i >>> 2) & 0x3333333333333333L;//2
    i = (i & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL) << 4 | (i >>> 4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL;//3
    i = (i & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL) << 8 | (i >>> 8) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL;//4
    i = (i << 48) | ((i & 0xffff0000L) << 16) |
        ((i >>> 16) & 0xffff0000L) | (i >>> 48);//5
    return i;
}
```

I can understand line 1,2,3,4, but not 5! How does it work?

I group the 64 bits to 8 groups,that is 1 is the first 8 bits, 2 is the second 8 bits, and so on.

Then after line 4,the sequence like `4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5`

and I think line 5 working as below before the `|` operation:

```
6,5,0,0,0,0,0,0-->(i << 48)
8,7,0,0,0,0,0,0-->((i & 0xffff0000L) << 16)
0,0,0,0,4,3,2,1-->((i >>> 16) & 0xffff0000L)
0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1-->(i >>> 48)
```

But, I don't know where dose it wrong or whether it is wrong! Thinking about it almost about a whole day!

Somebody can help me!! Thanks.

oh, i made a mistake like this:

```
6,5,0,0,0,0,0,0-->(i << 48)
0,0,8,7,0,0,0,0-->((i & 0xffff0000L) << 16)
0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0-->((i >>> 16) & 0xffff0000L)
0,0,0,0,0,0,4,3-->(i >>> 48)
```

but i alse think it is wrong! i think the right sequence is `8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1`

i am so sorry that i make some mistakes! it works right as below:

after line 4, the right pattern is:`2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7`

```
8,7,0,0,0,0,0,0-->(i << 48)
0,0,6,5,0,0,0,0-->((i & 0xffff0000L) << 16)
0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0-->((i >>> 16) & 0xffff0000L)
0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1-->(i >>> 48)
```

Comment: That smells headache, I hope that it wasn't an interview question !

Comment: @Jerome I would rather prefer leaving the cabin if it is asked in an interview....

Comment: not a interview question.it is the implication of reverse method in Long.java

Comment: 5 lines in java I'm sure I can fit this all in one line in C :)

Comment: @Jesus Ramos can you explain it for me? am i make any mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Line 1 swaps adjacent single bits in pairs (0 <-> 1; 2 <-> 3; etc.). Lines 2-4 swaps adjacent sequences of two bits, 4 bits, and 8 bits. At that point, the original value has been transformed into four blocks of 16 bits with each block the reverse of what it had been at the start. Line 5 then rearranges the 4 blocks. Basically, line 5 combines two steps into one: swapping two pairs of 16-bit blocks and swapping one pair of 32-bit blocks. The logic is:

- `(i << 48)` moves the rightmost 16-bit block to the left position, leaving all other bits zero
- `((i & 0xffff0000L) << 16)` moves the second block from the right to be the second block from the left (all other bits zero)
- `((i >>> 16) & 0xffff0000L)` moves the second block from the left to be the second block from the right (all other bits zero)
- `(i >>> 48)` moves the leftmost block to the right position (all other bits zero)

Then these four values are `|`-ed together to produce the final reversal. If it had been done in two steps, it would be two statements that look just like the first four statements, but with different mask patterns.

I think that after line 4, the pattern is `2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7`, not `4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5` as you assumed. The four pieces of line 5 then are:

```
8,7,0,0,0,0,0,0-->(i << 48)
0,0,6,5,0,0,0,0-->((i & 0xffff0000L) << 16)
0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0-->((i >>> 16) & 0xffff0000L)
0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1-->(i >>> 48)
```

Comment: hi, i am wrong,after line 4,the pattern is 2,1,4,3,8,7,6,5.thank you so much!

Comment: @liuxiaori - Are you sure that's the pattern after line 4? I think it should be `2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7`.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt isn't quite correct. Here's the corrected version:

```
2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7 --> i       //  Assume this sequence after line 4
8,7,0,0,0,0,0,0 --> (i << 48)
0,0,6,5,0,0,0,0 --> ((i & 0xffff0000L) << 16)
0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0 --> ((i >>> 16) & 0xffff0000L)
0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1 --> (i >>> 48)
```

Here's the two middle steps broken up:

```
2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7 --> i       //  Assume this sequence after line 4
0,0,0,0,6,5,0,0 --> (i & 0xffff0000L)
0,0,6,5,0,0,0,0 --> ((i & 0xffff0000L) << 16)

2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7 --> i       //  Assume this sequence after line 4
0,0,2,1,4,3,6,5 --> (i >>> 16)
0,0,0,0,4,3,0,0 --> ((i >>> 16) & 0xffff0000L)
```

---

Though I'm slightly surprised at why it isn't implemented as follows:

```
i = (i & 0x5555555555555555L) <<  1 | (i >>>  1) & 0x5555555555555555L;  //  1
i = (i & 0x3333333333333333L) <<  2 | (i >>>  2) & 0x3333333333333333L;  //  2
i = (i & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL) <<  4 | (i >>>  4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL;  //  3
i = (i & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL) <<  8 | (i >>>  8) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL;  //  4
i = (i & 0x0000ffff0000ffffL) << 16 | (i >>> 16) & 0x0000ffff0000ffffL;  //  5
i = (i & 0x00000000ffffffffL) << 32 | (i >>> 32) & 0x00000000ffffffffL;  //  6
```

It keeps the pattern consistent. <strike>And I think it reduces the # of operations as well.</strike>

**EDIT :** I see why it's implemented the way it is. The version in the question uses only **9 operations** for the final two reversals. The version here (lines 5 and 6) needs **10 operations**.

**Geez... talking about micro-optimization to the extreme...**

---

**EDIT 2:** Why didn't I think of this? Why doesn't `java.lang.Long` use this?

```
i = (i & 0x5555555555555555L) <<  1 | (i >>>  1) & 0x5555555555555555L;  //  1
i = (i & 0x3333333333333333L) <<  2 | (i >>>  2) & 0x3333333333333333L;  //  2
i = (i & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL) <<  4 | (i >>>  4) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fL;  //  3
i = (i & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL) <<  8 | (i >>>  8) & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffL;  //  4
i = (i & 0x0000ffff0000ffffL) << 16 | (i >>> 16) & 0x0000ffff0000ffffL;  //  5
i = (i << 32) | (i >>> 32)                                               //  6
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: `6,5,8,7,2,1,4,3` is the correct output. The first 4 lines already swap everything up to 8-bit granularity. Line 5 does the final 16-bit, and 32-bit swaps.

Comment: I think the correct output is supposed to be `8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1`. I also think the code itself is correct. In addition to the mistake you noted, the pattern after line 4 is not what OP thought, but rather `2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7` (every 16-bit block reversed, not every 32-bit block).

Comment: and i have the same question as your's.why it implemented as you write.

Comment: It keeps the same pattern. So once you understand one of those lines, you understand all of them. So there's no need to "decipher" that last line. EDIT: I see why it's implemented the way it is. It saves 1 operand. The version I gave needs 10, while the version in your question has only 9... geez...

Comment: that is you are the author of Long.java? is that right? is really you??!!

Comment: No, I'm not involved in Java development. Why did you think so? It's actually been a while since I've used Java.